# Why isn't keyboard inputs working when trying to use python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, input, keyboard

So basically when I click the letter "a" I want to be able to send a message to the client. Anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this. Here are the two codes:

Server Code:

```
//ServerCode
import socket
import keyboard

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        clientsocket.send(bytes("hi","utf-8"))
```

Client Code:

```
//ClientCode
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

while True:
    try:
        msg = s.recv(11)
        print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
    except:
        print("not there")
```

Comment: Were you holding down the a key when you ran the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up the connection loop, you need to loop once again for the keyboard to rest.

as for the files:

sever:

```
import socket
import keyboard

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1234))
s.listen(5)
pressed = True
while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    print("Connection from {address} has been established.")
    while pressed:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            client.send(bytes("hi","utf-8"))
            pressed = False
```

client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

while True:
     msg = s.recv(11)
     print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

**you need to loop both files if you want to print each time the 'a' is pressed**

sever:

```
import socket
import keyboard

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1234))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    print("Connection from {address} has been established.")
    while 1:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            client.send(bytes("hi","utf-8"))
```

client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

while True:
     while 1:
         msg = s.recv(11)
         print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

good luck :)

Comment: @user253751, If you're asking why it's 1, this is just a method to return True.If you are asking why I use a loop, it is because the program will run every time a key is pressed